# Bootstrap panel header text clipping out

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, hyperlink, panel, clip

I made two columns with panels in which hold responsive images. The panels have headers with links to those images. When resizing the viewport horizontally, the links clip out of the header.

[image: links clipping]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default behavior in CSS, but can change it by setting the `overflow-wrap` and the `word-wrap` properties.

```
.word-wrap-fix {
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

[Here](http://www.bootply.com/xf5RfB73hH) is a working example where there are two panels with a very long title and in one the `.word-wrap-fix` is applied.

[This link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/prevent-long-urls-from-breaking-out-of-container/) covers it pretty well and provides a few examples.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This helped.